# Expected Number of Visits - why is $E_x[N_x]=\sum_{n \geq 1} p_{x,x}^{(n)}$

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expectation

Suppose $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a discrete-time time-homogeneous Markov chain with transition probabilities $$P[X_{n+1}= y \mid X_{1}=x] = p_{x,y}^{(n)}.$$ Let $$N_x:=\sum_{n \geq 1} 1( X_n=x)$$ denote the number of visits to $x$. We use subscript $x$ to indicate that we start at state $x$.

Why is it true that 
$$E_x[N_x]=\sum_{n \geq 1} p_{x,x}^{(n)}?$$

At least, often, for defining recurrence, the following is used:

We have that a state is recurrent iff $E_x[N_x]=\infty$ and transient if $E_x[N_x]< \infty$. And often, it is written that a state is recurrent iff
$\sum_{n \geq 1} p_{x,x}^{(n)}= \infty$ and transient if the sum is convergent.

I see that $N_x$ takes values in $\{0,1 ,\dotsc\}$, and hence

$$E_x[N_x]=\sum_{n \geq 1} P_x[N_x \geq n],$$ but I do not see why (or whether?) $p_{x,x}^{(n)}$ and $P_x[N_x \geq n]$ are related.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}_x N_x=\mathbb{E}_x\sum_{n \geq 1} 1\{X_n=x\}=\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{E}_x[1\{X_n=x\}]=\sum_{n \geq 1} P_x\{X_n=x\}=\sum_{n \geq 1} p^{(n)}(x,x)$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot. Actually it is quite straight-forward . :-)

Comment: By the way: are you using Montone Convergence here in the second equality?

Comment: @user136457: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions